# How is Println able to access unexported fields

Tags: go

```
package test

import (
    "fmt"
)

type DP struct {
    array []int
    cols  int
}

func (v *DP) Init(rs, cs int) {
    v.array = make([]int, rs*cs, rs*cs)
    v.cols = cs
}

func (v *DP) Get(r, c int) int {
    return v.array[r*v.cols+c]
}
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "test"
)

func main() {
    var k, x, n int
    var dp test.DP
    fmt.Scanf("%d %d %d", &n, &k, &x)
    dp.Init(n, k)
    fmt.Println(dp) // print the contents of dp.array
    fmt.Printf("%d %d %d", n, k, x)
}
```

How is Println able to access all the unexported fields.
Why is it not giving any error like *dp.array undefined (cannot refer to unexported field or method array)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `fmt.Print` family uses `reflect`, and `reflect` grants power of accessing unexported fields, with `reflect.Value.Field`. Note that unexported field can only be read that way, but not written.

Some code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type A struct {
    A int
    b int
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    a := A{1, 2}
    va := reflect.ValueOf(&a).Elem()
    exported := va.Field(0)
    unexported, unexportedName := va.Field(1), va.Type().Field(1)
    fmt.Println(unexportedName, unexported)
    // exported settable but unexported not settable
    fmt.Println(exported.CanSet(), unexported.CanSet())
    exported.Set(reflect.ValueOf(int(3)))
    fmt.Println(a)
    // this will panic
    unexported.Set(reflect.ValueOf(int(5)))
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/6mhFR7efPEc